Does the generalization of linearity have a popular name?
Let $F, G$ be quasi-normed spaces. In "Fourier analysis" writen by H. Komatsu in Japanese, he says that an operator $T:F\to G$ is quasi-additive if there is a constant $C$ for which
$||T(af)||_G=|a| \cdot ||Tf||_G$ and
\begin{equation}
||Tf-Tg||_G\le C||T(f-g)||_G
\end{equation}
for every $f,g \in F$ and $a\in \mathbb{C}$ (and he seldom uses the notion).
However, I couldn't find other materials using the word "quasi-additive".
Does the concept have another (more popular) name?

Do you have some natural nonnadditive examples ?

@RyszardSzwarc The Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator is an example.

Right. Besides  operators of the form $Tf=S|f|,$ where $S$ is bounded linear and $Sf\ge 0$ for $f\ge 0$ are quasi additive.
